# Заполнение шаблона документа Word/Создание и заполнение документа Word с нуля Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую директиву Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word для работы непосредственно с Word'ом, однако не могу понять, как заполнить программно документ на основе шаблона или же создать его с нуля и также программно заполнить нужной информацией. Сделать планирую что-то по типу того, что изображено ниже на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы вам сочувствуем. Но чтобы рассчитывать на ответ надо сперва задать конкретный вопрос.

Comment: уже несколько раз скидывал свой старый проект https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/AutoSertificate-.NET может поможет

Comment: @AntonNikolaev Спасибо большое! В скором времени посмотрю и скажу, помогло или нет, чтобы можно было как-нибудь выделить ответ